# how do you stop an ActionListener from remembering previous events

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

i'm only new enough to java. i'm tring to fill a 6x6 grid in with 6 differnet colours without the same colour appearing in the same row or column. in my code i set up a 6x6 grid of JButtons stored in an array called buttons. when i press one of these JButtons a 6x1 grid of JButtons is set up called paintBox. the JButtons in paintBox are declared at the top of the program as fillRed,fillYellow etc. when i press fillRed it sets the back round of the JButton from the 6x6 grid red but when i press a different JButton from the 6x6 grid and try set that to yellow it sets it to yellow but also sets the original JButton that was set to red to yellow as well. any help would be great. 
thanks

```
import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    public class Grid4 extends JFrame implements ActionListener
    {
        private ColourGrid paintBox = null;
        private JButton fillRed = new JButton("Red");
        private JButton fillYellow = new JButton("Yellow");
        private JButton fillBlue = new JButton("Blue");
        private JButton fillGreen = new JButton("Green");
        private JButton fillPurple = new JButton("Purple");
        private JButton fillBrown = new JButton("Brown");
        private JButton[] paintButton = {fillRed,fillYellow,fillBlue,fillGreen,fillPurple,fillBrown};
        private Color[] colours = {Color.RED, Color.YELLOW, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, new Color(102, 0, 102), new Color(102, 51, 0)};
        public static void main(String[] args) // sets up a 6x6 grid
        {
            int rows = 6;
            int cols = 6;
            int size = 600;
            Grid4 grid = new Grid4(rows, cols);
            grid.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            grid.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(size, size));
            grid.pack();
            grid.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            grid.setVisible(true);
        }
        // main
        public Grid4(int rows, int cols) // makes the 6x6 main grid a grid of JButtons
        {
            int rowSize = 6;
            int colSize = 6;
            int gridSize = 600;
            JButton[][] buttons; //makes an array called buttons
            buttons = new JButton[rowSize][colSize];
            Container pane = getContentPane();
            pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, cols));
            for(int j =0; j < rows; j++){
                for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
                    buttons[j][i] = new JButton("");
                    buttons[j][i].setOpaque(true);
                    buttons[j][i].setName("");
                    buttons[j][i].addActionListener(this);
                    buttons[j][i].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                    pane.add(buttons[j][i]);
                }
            }
        }               //end of grid constructor

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            if ( paintBox != null && paintBox.isShowing())//stops more than one paintBox from opening
                paintBox.dispose();
            if( e.getSource() instanceof JButton){// sets
                ((JButton)e.getSource()).setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            } 

            int rows = 6;
            int cols = 1;
            int size = 300;
            paintBox = new ColourGrid(rows, cols,(JButton)e.getSource());
            paintBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(size/3, size));
            paintBox.pack();
            paintBox.setVisible(true);
        }

        public class ColourGrid extends JFrame
        { 
            private JButton buttonPress;

            public ColourGrid(int rows, int cols, JButton button)
            {

                buttonPress = button;
                Container pane = getContentPane();
                pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, cols));
                for (int i = 0; i < paintButton.length; i++) {
                    paintButton[i].setOpaque(true);
                    paintButton[i].addActionListener(buttonAction);
                    paintButton[i].setForeground(new Color(100,100,100));
                    paintButton[i].setBackground(colours[i]);
                    pane.add(paintButton[i]);
                }
            }
            private ActionListener buttonAction = new ActionListener()
            {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a)
            {
                if(a.getSource() instanceof JButton){
                    if((JButton)a.getSource()== fillRed){
                    buttonPress.setBackground(Color.RED);
                    dispose();
                    }
                    else if((JButton)a.getSource()== fillYellow){
                    buttonPress.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                    dispose();
                    }
                    else if((JButton)a.getSource()== fillBlue){
                    buttonPress.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                    dispose();
                    }
                    else if((JButton)a.getSource()== fillGreen){
                    buttonPress.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                    dispose();
                    }
                    else if((JButton)a.getSource()== fillPurple){
                    buttonPress.setBackground(new Color(102, 0, 102));
                    dispose();
                    }
                    else if((JButton)a.getSource()== fillBrown){
                    buttonPress.setBackground(new Color(102, 51, 0));
                    dispose();
                    }
                } 

            }
        };
        }
    }
```

Comment: I suggest to use a `JColorChooser` instead of a `ColourGrid`.  If a color chooser is inappropriate for some reason, put the `ColourGrid` in a `JDialog` that is set modal `true`.  (And for good measure, rename it to `ColorGrid` just to be consistent with the usual spelling used in the J2SE.)

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that your color buttons are in the Grid4 class. Each time you create a new ColourGrid object, you add the very same color buttons into the new ColourGrid JFrame and re-add an ActionListener to the same buttons. So each time this occurs, the JButtons accumulate another ActionListener, and pretty soon whenever a color button is pressed, many ActionListeners fire, both old and new, and all the buttons change color.

The solution is to have the color buttons be part of the ColourGrid class, not the Grid4 class:

```
public class ColourGrid extends JFrame {
  private JButton fillRed = new JButton("Red");
  private JButton fillYellow = new JButton("Yellow");
  private JButton fillBlue = new JButton("Blue");
  private JButton fillGreen = new JButton("Green");
  private JButton fillPurple = new JButton("Purple");
  private JButton fillBrown = new JButton("Brown");
  private JButton[] paintButton = { fillRed, fillYellow, fillBlue, fillGreen,
        fillPurple, fillBrown };
  private Color[] colours = { Color.RED, Color.YELLOW, Color.BLUE,
        Color.GREEN, new Color(102, 0, 102), new Color(102, 51, 0) };

  private JButton buttonPress;
```

This way, each time you create a new ColourGrid object, it gets fresh new JButtons with only one ActionListener attached to each, and only the most recent grid button's color changes.

Otherwise, all recommendations that Andrew gave you are very good recommendations.

Comment: thanks to both of you for the advice its working fine now. really appreicate the help.